# EF5 code first datetime2, building a linq expression

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I want to force all my DateTime in my domain to be datetime2 on sql server. I know I can use:

```
Property(x => x.Field).HasColumnType("datetime2");
```

In my EntityTypeConfiguration derived classes.

But I would like to code something less "verbose". I try the following:

```
public static void SetDateTimeColumnType<T>(EntityTypeConfiguration<T> etc) where T : class {
    Type t = typeof(T);
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)) {
        if (pi.PropertyType.Name == "DateTime") {
            etc.Property(x => (DateTime)pi.GetValue(x)).HasColumnType("datetime2");
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following exception :

```
The expression 'x => Convert(value(EFVIPRepository.ContextUtilities+<>c__DisplayClass0`1[ValkirIP.Domain.Entities.IPRight]).pi.GetValue(x))' 
is not a valid property expression. 
The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty' VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'. 
Use dotted paths for nested properties: C#: 't => t.MyProperty.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty.MyProperty'.
```

I think my real question is how to build a "property expresssion" from the name of the property, if possible.

Thank you in advance

===== EDIT =====

I also try

```
Expression expr = Expression.Property(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Variable(t), pi);
etc.Property((Expression<Func<T, DateTime>>)expr).HasColumnType("datetime2");
```

with the following exception:

```
Impossible d'effectuer un cast d'un objet de type 'System.Linq.Expressions.PropertyExpression' en type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[ValkirIP.Domain.Entities.IPRight,System.DateTime]]'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must build correct `Expression Tree`.

Try this:

```
public static void SetDateTimeColumnType<T>(EntityTypeConfiguration<T> etc) where T : class
{
    Type t = typeof(T);
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        if (pi.PropertyType.Name == "DateTime")
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(t, "x");
            var property = Expression.Property(parameter, pi.Name);
            var lmbd Expression.Lambda<Func<T, DateTime>>(property, parameter);
            etc.Property(lmbd).HasColumnType("datetime2");
        }
    }
}
```